# PyScripter - cannot termiate Run with KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, pyscripter, keyboardinterrupt

I write alot of small apps where I use

```
try:
   print "always does this until I Ctrl+C"


Except KeyboardInterrupt:
   print "finish program"
```

I've just began to move away from using IDLE and booted up PyScripter. However CTRL+C no longer works. Is it possible to still send in a `KeyboardInterrupt` while using the built-in interpreter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PyScripter if you just want to terminate a running program you can always re-initialize the remote engine:

- Application Run Menu > Python Engine > Reinitialize Python Engine or
- Interpreter context menu > Python Engine > Reinitialize Python Engine or
- Keyboard shortcut CTRL-F2

[Source, Psyscripter Author](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/PyScripter/La3kYQqmqow/eZ0-07ZJnccJ)

Answer (score 0):

I keep answering my own questions, but I believe they are valid..

The PyScripter google group has one implementation where they import a progress bar and kill it, simulating an interrupt. however, this is not the same as a keyboard interrupt. Looks like i'm out of luck until a new implementation.

Having Said That, can anyone suggest another novel way to terminate programs at a user's discretion (without using threads :p)?